# How to discuss the convergence and divergence of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_1\in\mathbb{R}$,$x_{n+1}=x_n-x^3_{n}(n\geqslant1)$,when does $\{x_n\}$ converge and diverge?
I already know that $\{x_n\}$ converges when $|x_1|\leqslant1$.Because when $|x_1|\leqslant1$, $\{x_n\}$ is a monotone bounded sequence.But I don't know how to discuss it next.

Comment: Well, what is going to happen if $x_1$ is _just slightly_ greater than 1?

Comment: @Ivan Neretin  Thank you, if $x_1$ is just slightly greater than 1.$x_n$ monotonic decreasing.Because $x_{n+1}-x_n<0$.But there seems to be no lower bound

Comment: Think again. $1.1 \to -0.231 \to -0.219 \to -0.208 \to -0.199 \to -0.191\dots$ - is that decreasing?

Comment: @Ivan Neretin I'm sorry.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin So do you mean that when $x_1>1$, the monotone increment is unbounded?

Comment: Not necessarily. See, you know what happens if $|x_1|<1$. Now what if $|x_{11}|<1$ and _you don't even know_ the previous terms?

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Yes, so there is no way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why, of course there is.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Would you please write down the answer, thank you

Comment: Think in terms of decreasing $|x_n|$ and not in terms of increasing or decreasing $x_n$.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin  Well, I'll think about it